# Как работает Crawl Errors in Google?

Tags: php, google-webmasters

В Веб-мастер от Google, получил **Crawl Errors**.   Показывает что на странице есть ссылки при переходе на которые получается 503 ошибка. 
Когда захожу на указанную страницу где есть эти ссылки, то в исходном коде данных ссылок нету.
**Вопрос**: Как работает данные сервис? Отключает ли скрипты при сканировании страницы или нет и тд.

Comment: А по правой кнопке в инспекторе кода они есть?

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov нету. Но на странице есть два select'a.
Например, в первом идет список брендов авто, а второй селект disabled пока не выбран первый.  
И вот гугл показывает, что есть ссылка audi/jazz, но такого точно нету.  
Но в инспекторе кода есть полный список всех брендов и всех моделей в Option.

Comment: Вообще ПС не исполняют JS. Но есть исключения, например простой document.write они анализируют и т.д. Вот ссылочка по теме https://devaka.ru/articles/complex-javascript-for-google

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov Спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: Добавил более расширенный ответ в ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По дефолту ПС **не исполняют JS**, поскольку это довольно ресурсозатратно.

Но при этом есть куча исключений и ньюансов.

Во первых чем более продвинутая ПС - тем больше у нее ресурсов, ведь например тот же Google в https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ замечательно исполняет JS, это видно на картинках рендеринга сайта справа, что мешает ему использовать это в спорных ситуациях? В то же время какой нибудь "Спутник" не может себе этого позволить.

Во вторых, существуют разного рода заплатки, которые могут анализировать простой JS, например ссылка через document.write наверяняка будет распознана почти всеми ПС. Вот исследование по теме http://devaka.ru/articles/complex-javascript-for-google, оно хоть и старое, но суть я думаю понятна.

Ну в третьих, есть еще браузеры. Например Chrome отстукивает в Google с какой страницы и куда ходит пользователь, и если он увидит что был переход со страницы А, на страницу Б через событие JS, то тут как ни шифруй - вряли что-то поможет.